# Sorting SQL queries using CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been researching how SQL queries work and how to use the CASE statement, but with no luck. I cannot figure out how to get this working.

I have a SQL table shown here:
[image: SQL table]

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `unsold`
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN keywords LIKE '%tv%' THEN name LIKE '%tv%' ELSE description LIKE '%tv%' END);
```

The result is the same as the default table

I am trying to sort them by if the keywords column LIKE "tv" then display the results first but order by name LIKE "tv". Otherwise, display name column where name is like "tv".

I haven't used much SQL up until now if you can't tell.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: yes there is already a meta thread for not posting images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I was unaware of that, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want multiple keys for the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (keywords LIKE '%tv%') DESC,
         (CASE WHEN keywords LIKE '%tv%' THEN name LIKE '%tv%' END) DESC,
         (description LIKE '%tv%') DESC
```

I added `DESC` so the "true" values are first.